# Exercice about the group of unit $(\mathbb Z/21\mathbb Z)^\times $.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Let $(\mathbb Z/21\mathbb Z)^\times$ the group of units of $\mathbb Z/21\mathbb Z$.

1) How many element in $(\mathbb Z/21\mathbb Z)^\times$ ?

2) Is it isomorphic to an abelian group ?

3) Is it cyclique ?

**My answers**

1) $|(\mathbb Z/21\mathbb Z)^\times |=\varphi(21)=\varphi(3\cdot 7)=\varphi(3)\cdot \varphi(7)=2\cdot 6=12$

where $\varphi$ is the euler totient.

**Q1) is it correct ?**

2) By chinese theorem $(\mathbb Z/21\mathbb Z)^\times \cong (\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)^\times \times (\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z)^\times $
Since $(\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)^\times $ is a group with 2 element it's isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and $(\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z)^\times $ is an abelian group with 6 element, and thus it's isomorphic $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$. But $[2]_6^2=[4]_6$ and $[2]_6^3=8=[2]_6\neq [1]_6$ therefore $2$ is not an element of 2 nor 3 and thus the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ ?

**Q2) Is it correct ?**

3) I would says now since a product of abelian group is never cyclique (since it's not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/k\mathbb Z$ for a certain $k$).

**Q3) Is it correct ?**

Comment: Question 2 is a bit weird; $(\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z})^\times$ *is* abelian, so of course it's trivially isomorphic to an abelian group. For the rest of your proof, $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ is actually isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, which means $(\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z})^\times \cong  \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. This is indeed non-cyclic but not for the reason you gives, because that's not true.

Comment: @ArnaudD. : If $|G|=k$ is and $G$ is cyclic, don't we have $G\cong \mathbb Z/k\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: @MSE Yes of course, but it's not true that a product of abelian groups is never cyclic.